# Object moves and rotates in opposite direction with Armature modifier on

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I have a rig with a body, arms and legs. I noticed that when I rotate the body, the bones at the base of the limbs rotate appropriately, but the actual meshes parented to those bones fly off the armature [Picture 1]. When I go to Object Mode and try to move the arm by itself, it moves opposite to how it should in the z- and y-axes (the bones extend along the x-axis) [Picture 2]. Rotation is similar. I've found that it stops behaving like this when I turn the Armature modifier off.

Things that might be helpful:

- The arms are parented to the shoulders which are parented to the body
- The legs are parented directly to the body
- The legs don't exhibit this behavior at all, but still seem to rotate wrong
- The arms and legs are each a single object with the mirror modifier

Why might this be happening, and how can I fix it? I'm completely new to rigging so thank you for any help you can offer!

[image: T-pose where I"ve tried to move the arms up, but they go down instead]

[image: Pose mode, the armature rotates appropriately but the arms and legs fly off]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots Sure, here it is [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=d6mOj62L" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/d6mOj62L/)

I should note that since I posted this I found that unparenting the arm and leg from the body fixes the behavior, but the problem still happens in the mirrored halves. Thank you!

Comment: It's a bit of a mess in my opinion, instead of fiwing it I would apply the Mirror, join all the limbs to the body to make one object, parent With Empty Groups then assign the vertices to the vertex group they should be part of